# How to create python boxplot on most significant data of a variable

Tags: python, variables, boxplot

My `dataframe` contains information about certain products (description, components, day of production, manufacturer, price, etc...). I want to check whether the identity of a manufacturer has any impact on the price. But since I have hundreds of manufacturers I only want to do a `boxplot` with the ten most significant manufacturers.

I manage to sort the manufacturer by importance but not to `boxplot` the 10 most important manufacturers.

```
df['manufacturers'].value_counts()[:10]
```

Pipeline with `boxplot` after such code does not work

same as above

Comment: Please Include `df['manufacturers'].head(10)` (or just `df.head(10)`) in your question, copy and paste the text then format as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`). Also include all code that you are having a problem with and explain how it is deficient.. Please read [mcve]

Comment: Please show *Pipeline with boxplot after such code does not work* and explain why it does not work. Error? Undesired resilt?